# Symfony form theme custom attribute on row

Tags: forms, symfony, custom-data-attribute

Okay, so I have a form theme for custom radio button. In the form theme I render the label as an image. The image is basically a call to a route (which returns BinaryResponse):

```
<img src="{{ path('the_route_name', {'slideImage': value}) }}" class="slideImage">
```

Now, this works, however, the same form type needs to be used for slideshow background selector. The rendering is the same, however the route call and parameters are different.

Slide image: showSlideImage with parameter slideImage
Slideshow background: showBackgroundImage with parameter slideshowBackground

What my idea was, is to send a custom data attribute to the form for the route name (I can make both parameters the same name to avoid that issue).

I tried the following in my twig template where the form is rendered:

```
{{ form_row(form.background, {'attr': {'data-path': 'path'}}) }}
```

(background is an EntityType with multiple as false and expanded as true)

However, when I put a dump in my form theme

```
{{ dump(attr) }}
```

It shows an empty array. I've tried changing `attr` to `row_attr` but that didn't change anything. How can I send a custom data attribute to the form theme for it to render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I had to use `choice_attr`:

```
'choice_attr' => function($choice, $key, $value) {
    return ['path' => 'showSlideImage'];
},
```

I tried using `choice_attr` before, but I wasn't using a callback function and thus I did it the wrong way. And then I can just use `attr.path` to get the right value.